Does an ISR pause PWM?
I have a Nano producing a PWM output from one of its pins. This PWM signal cannot stop as it drives a filament for a VFD display(if it stops, nothing shows). However, I need to capture the pulses from an external clock in order to shift display data in accordance with the multiplexing timer using an ISR sequence.
However, does an interrupt temporarily pause PWM while the ISR is being executed?

No, it doesn't.
An interrupt request interrupts the processor inside the
microcontroller, which stops whatever it is doing in order to run the
interrupt service routine (or ISR). The PWM is generated by a timer,
which is a peripheral and does not care about what the processor is doing.
